# Command line issues

Tags: terminal, bash, iterm, zsh

I'm trying to execute two commands in a single line:

```
pkill "something" && runsomething
```

- when executing each command separately, both work.
- When executed together with "&&", only the first one works

when using something other than pkill, it works:

```
 sleep 5 && runsomething
```

How can I make "pkill" play nice with multiple commands in a single line?

Comment: `&&` tells the shell to run the second command *only if* the first succeeds (specifically, if it exits with a status of zero). Apparently, `pkill` is exiting with an error status.

Comment: Yep. that was the reason. pkill failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to put a semi-colon between the two commands instead of &&. I just tried using the semi-colon and it worked fine.